# How to configure webpack to generate source map with links to react files?

Tags: webpack

I tried using this

```
devtool: "inline-source-map",
```

but when I see errors in console there is a link to **main.[hash].js**

What I want is to get links to react files, to be able to find and see code that caused error using webpack 5.

Comment: What does the `link` mean?